# Ajax function doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax

Works great in chrome, opera, firefox but not in IE browser,
  Any thoughts?
you can see an example here:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B08Mrlbnhv98a0dMUldSVmJLUlU&usp=sharing

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
      {
        var Fname = document.getElementsByName('FirstName')[0];
        var Lname = document.getElementsByName('LastName')[0];

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1hOViTOAdde6WgAdPFlobHzrNGhfZZ781Ba6EDC54kVs/formResponse",
            data: {
                "entry_2018163929":Fname.value,
                "entry_2125985135":Lname.value
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "XML",
            statusCode: ""
        });
        clear();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try wrapping the code in `ready`

Comment: @Tushar: If that were necessary, it wouldn't work in Chrome, either.

Comment: Check the developer tools (F12 usually) console log for errors - looking at the code, it's GNDN ... goes nowhere does nothing ... what are you expecting that to do anyway?

Comment: The code shown is fine provided the cross-origin request is allowed, so we need (a lot) more context. Use the debugger built into your browser to watch the code run and see where the problem occurs. The debugger is **always** the first tool to turn to.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - what would that code do? I must be misreading it

Comment: @JaromandaX: Provided the relevant elements exist, it would grab the value of the `name="FirstName"` and `name="LastName"` elements and send them to a URL on docs.google.com via POST. The `dataType` option is pointless as the user isn't using the result, and the `statusCode` option is misused, but I doubt either of those causes an issue. The outer block is just a block (also pointless). The `clear` at the end may well be throwing an error; `document.clear` (which is also available without the `document.` prefix) was never standardized and was deprecated years and years back...

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - unusual to see ajax that does nothing on the browser - absolutely no feedback whatsoever on the client side

Comment: @JaromandaX: Yes, but fire-and-forget isn't entirely unknown. Seems to be what the OP did with the question, as well. :-) My guess is that this is a small part of something larger and has been over-trimmed. But as the OP has wandered off...

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, the only warning in explorer is "DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching" and on Firefox "This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1."